Returning and using an reqwest::Response from an async method
I am hoping to improve some logic that crafts and returns a Future for a reqwest::Response by adding in logic to catch, reauthenticate, and retry when the response is a 401. However, even before I get to that retry logic, my attempts to move the creation of the reqwest::Response into an async method (in which the reauthentication logic would be placed) are failing with lifetime errors.
The original working code to be replaced is a non-async method in the struct returning a boxed future; self.Client is a reqwest::Client and the the project is using a tokio runtime:
    pub fn demo_good(
        &mut self,
        url: Url,
    ) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<Response, Error>> + Send>> {
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert("fake_key".to_string(), "fake_value".to_string());
        let response = self.client.post(url).json(&map).send();
        Box::pin(response)
    }

However, as soon as I try to start moving the self.client.post(...)... logic into an async method of the struct, I get a lifetime error:
    // POST to the execute_url, handling reauthentication
    async fn demo_post(
        &mut self,
        url: Url,
        body: HashMap<String, String>,
    ) -> Result<Response, Error> {
        // Run first request
        let response = self.client.post(url).json(&body).send().await;
        // Todo: catch 401s, reauth, and repeat
        dbg!(&response);
        // Return
        response
    }

    pub fn demo_bad(
        &mut self,
        url: Url,
    ) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<Response, Error>> + Send>> {
        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert("fake_key".to_string(), "fake_value".to_string());
        let response = self.demo_post(url, map);
        Box::pin(response)
    }

   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:41:9
   |
35 |         &mut self,
   |         - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
41 |         Box::pin(response)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
   |
help: to declare that the trait object captures data from argument `self`, you can add an explicit `'_` lifetime bound
   |
37 |     ) -> Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<Response, Error>> + Send + '_>> {
   |                                                                    

I could follow the suggestion here, but this doesn't actually capture any more data from the argument self than did the original working demo_good method. Furthermore, I actually do want to return this future Response for use elsewhere in the codebase, and I worry that the new lifetime constraint will just kick the problem down further, leading to errors like error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value that I didn't have before.
Is there an alternate way to make a strategy like this work, maybe by specifying lifetime parameters in some of the method signatures? Or is it doomed to fail, because of the difference between the original reqwest methods (which are non-async and return Futures) and the wrapper method I added (which is async), and there is some different design to use?
Here is a link to this code in the Rust playground:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5e92c7a6977c2a4cdaa51dae7419c266

"this doesn't actually capture any more data from the argument self" - the generated code does in fact store all the reference arguments in the returned Future as per here. It makes no attempt at analyzing usage of parameters within the body of the function.

@user2407038 Ah, OK, maybe what I should have said it that anything getting so captured isn't logically necessary because it's not using those references any more than the original working demo_good, and I want to  figure out how to make that explicit

Maybe this recommendation -- non-async method using an async move block https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-define-async-methods-without-capturing-lifetime-of-self/10708 -- is the way to go?

It seems that you have already found the answer to your question. Although for the function in question there's no syntactically nicer way to do this, you would just have let act = self.client.post(...); async move { let response = act.await; response }. But for more complicated functions using async blocks may solve the issue.

You can convince the compiler by using impl Trait instead of async fn:
// POST to the execute_url, handling reauthentication
fn demo_post(
    &mut self,
    url: Url,
    body: HashMap<String, String>,
) -> impl Future<Output = Result<Response, Error>> {
    let request = self.client.post(url);
    async move {
        // Run first request
        let response = request.json(&body).send().await;
        // Todo: catch 401s, reauth, and repeat
        dbg!(&response);
        // Return
        response
    }
}

